# Adding 2 decimal numbers in strings, retaining precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, rounding

I have 2 strings, each containing a decimal number, and we can assume they have the same precision.

I can't just hard-code the precision because these sets of strings may have different precision sometimes.

I simply want to add both of their values and have the sum retain the precision of those aforementioned values.

One of the values may have a negative, which is why I'd like to avoid string splicing, which was my initial idea.

My Code:

```
str1 = "0.16107000" 
str2 = "0.00000270"
total = abs(float(str1)) + abs(float(str2))
print("Total is " + str(total))
```

Output:

```
Total is 0.16107269999999999
```

Desired Output:

```
Total is 0.16107270
```

Another example which makes things trickier:

```
str1 = "70.00000000" 
str2 = "0.00131251"
```

I need the total to be `70.00131251`

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is dupe question

Comment: By "precision" do you mean decimal places? (There are other ways to measure precision, such as significant digits.) What is the largest number of decimal places and significant digits that could appear? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Right, decimal places. I'm using Python 3.7.
Largest number of digits following the decimal would be 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code. It seems more complicated than is required, but the complexity is needed to handle the general case. If the two numbers have differing numbers of decimal places, this code will use the larger, which is what you want if the strings denote exact values.

```
def get_decimal_places(dec_str: str) -> int:
    """Return the number of decimal places expressed in a number in a
    string. The string must have only an optional leading sign, decimal
    digits, and an optional single decimal point. No check is done on
    these requirements. If the string has no decimal point, the returned
    value is zero.
    """
    if "." in dec_str:
        return len(dec_str) - dec_str.find(".") - 1
    else:
        return 0


str1 = "0.16107000" 
str2 = "0.00000270"

dec_places = max(get_decimal_places(str1), get_decimal_places(str2))
print(f"Total is {float(str1) + float(str2):.{dec_places}f}")
```

This code gives the desired output:

```
Total is 0.16107270
```

If you use your other example,

```
str1 = "70.00000000"
str2 = "0.00131251"
```

this also gives the desired output:

```
Total is 70.00131251
```

and for your example in your answer,

```
str1 = "-70.00000000"
str2 = "0.00131251"
```

the output is yet again as desired:

```
Total is -69.99868749
```

And finally, for this tricky example

```
str1 = "0.10"
str2 = "0.0000"
```

the output is also as desired:

```
Total is 0.1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this doesn't work when:

str1 = "70.00000000"
str2 = "0.00131251"

I need the total to be 70.00131251, but I end up with 70.001313

Comment: @Dingo: Thanks for pointing out an error in my answer. I have now changed my answer. My current code works in that case and in many other cases as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 8
str1 = "0.16107000" 
str2 = "0.00000270"
total = Decimal(str1)+Decimal(str2)
print("Total is " + str(total))
# Total is 0.16107270
```

Comment: The questioner stated that you cannot "just hard-code the precision because these sets of strings may have different precision sometimes." This answer hard-codes the precision at 8 decimal places.

Comment: Similarly to ComplicatedPhenomenon and Rory Daulton's solution, 
when str1 = "70.00000000" and str2 = "0.00131251", the total is 70.001313 instead of 70.00131251, which is what I'd need.

Comment: @Dingo You can set `getcontext().prec = 10 ` then.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = 3.1234567
>>> x = float('{:.3f}'.format(x))
>>> x
3.123
```

add in your code

```
x = float('{:.9f}'.format(total))
print(x)
```

Comment: I don't think that it was a serious question. However, `.format()` would cut the remaining digits. He should use `str(round(total, num_of_digits))` to round to the last digit. But again seems like a silly question.

Comment: I'm making an API call and receiving those numbers as strings. I have to add them and make another API call where one parameter is the sum, and only the same precision I received earlier is accepted.

Pretty rude to dismiss my question as "silly".

Answer (score 0):

This is using ComplicatedPhenomenon's original code, his suggestion to increase getcontext().prec based on the **numbers** (excluding - sign) before the decimal, and Rory Daulton's code to determine what getcontext().prec to use based on the passed strings.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

def add_string_numbers(str1, str2):
    def get_decimal_places(dec_str: str) -> int:
        """Return the number of decimal places expressed in a number in a
        string. The string must have only an optional leading sign, decimal
        digits, and an optional single decimal point. If the string has no
        decimal point, the returned value is zero.
        """
        if "." in dec_str:
            return len(dec_str) - dec_str.find(".") + len([x for x in dec_str.split(".")[0] if x.isdigit()])
        else:
            return 0
    getcontext().prec = max(get_decimal_places(str1), get_decimal_places(str2))
    total = Decimal(str1) + Decimal(str2)    
    return total

str1 = "-70.00000000"
str2 = "0.00131251"

total = add_string_numbers(str1, str2)
print("Total is " + str(total))
```

Result:

```
Total is -69.99868749
```

Comment: Note that I changed my answer and no longer use the `decimal` module. My previous code did not work in all cases, while I believe my current one does.